# How to alter tags in HTML from an ng-include

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, web

So I'm fairly new to web programming and am trying to figure out an effective, organized, and minimal way to put together a website.  I pretty much have the whole website coded (tristangianola.com) but right now I hand wrote the code for the navigation bar explicitly in each html file. But now I'm trying to put the nav bar in one html file and import it into each web page using Ajax's "ng-include".  My question is...how can I alter specific tags in the ng-included file so that...based on what web page is open, that link will light up a different color.

Below is the nav bar code in its own individual file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <!--site navigation / toolbar-->
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li id="media"><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
        <li id="calendar"><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
        <li id="projects">
            <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="Bushcraft.html">Bushcraft</a></li>
                <li><a href="Spicerack.html">SpiceRack</a></li>
                <li><a href="LowTones.html">Low Tones</a></li>
                <li><a href="JohnMclaughlin.html">Being John Mclaughlin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And what I would like to do is in individual webpages such as media.html, I want to get the li attribute by the ID and replace the  tag with a  tag so that the css will change the link to blue.  Is ng-include still a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common problem and there are [tons](http://eznetu.com/current-link.html) of options, but my recommendation would be to do something similar to [Chris Coyer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/highlight-all-links-to-current-page/). Instead of replacing the tag, you can just add a class. Say you want that blue color to be on all elements with the "selected" class.

### Your CSS:

```
.selected {
     color: #a7d2ff;
}
```

---

### Your nav:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
$("menu li a").each(function(){
           if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
                   $(this).addClass("selected");
           }
   });
</script>
<body>
    <!--site navigation / toolbar-->
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li id="media"><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
        <li id="calendar"><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
        <li id="projects">
            <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="Bushcraft.html">Bushcraft</a></li>
                <li><a href="Spicerack.html">SpiceRack</a></li>
                <li><a href="LowTones.html">Low Tones</a></li>
                <li><a href="JohnMclaughlin.html">Being John Mclaughlin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Note that this will fail on your website for the items in the "Projects" section because they have URLs that don't tell you what section they're in (i.e. "tristangianola.com/Bushcraft.html" instead of "tristangianola.com/projects/Bushcraft.html"). To fix this just put the projects pages in the projects directory. Once you do this though, the above code still won't match because it won't be strictly `==` to "projects/someProject.html". For that, you'll need regular expressions (implemented with Javascript's `.match`):

```
<script>
$("menu li a").each(function(){
           if (location.pathname.match($(this).attr.href)){
                   $(this).addClass("selected");
           }
   });
</script>
```